# Saber se um vídeo pausou para carregar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos, vídeo

Estou usando o `shaka-player` para reproduzir um fluxo dash a partir de um servidor Nimble, mas andei lendo que o evento `waiting` nem sempre é a opção mais confiável, e de fato quando o vídeo para pra carregar a imagem simplesmente congela, e meu evento não está sendo ativado, logo eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma solução alternativa para saber se o vídeo parou para carregar?

Estou usando o waiting dessa forma

```
$("#video").bind("waiting", function(){
    $('.player-container .player-loading').show();
});
```

Comment: Quando você fala em "pausar", você se refere ao vídeo pausado por estar carregando (internet) ou o usuário clicar em pause para aguardar o vídeo carregar?

Comment: Pausar para carregar (causas de internet / conexão lenta)

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas ja olhou essa documentação?
https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/index.html

Comment: Já dei uma olhada, mas o problema também acontece as vezes mesmo quando o vídeo não está sendo executado pelo shaka-player, logo achei que seria interessante pensar numa solução mais "universal" para o problema

Comment: Você pode criar um timer para ser executado quando o video inicia e a cada segundo monitorar o tempo do video, se o atual for o mesmo de 1 segundo atrás o video esta parado.

Comment: O mesmo não pode ser usado com o próprio event timeUpdate ou progress do vídeo?

Comment: Acho que você está procurando por isso daqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399872/how-to-detect-whether-html5-video-has-paused-for-buffering

Answer (score 1):

Faz tempo que fiz isso, não consigo achar aqui... Mas, você pode definir .playing como uma propriedade personalizada para todos os elementos de mídia e acessá-lo quando necessário. Um exemplo:

```
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
    get: function(){
        return !!(this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
    }
})
```

E depois utilizar elementos de vídeo ou áudio, assim:

```
if(document.querySelector('video').playing){ // checks if element is playing right now
    // Do anything you want to
}
```

Não entendi muito bem sua dúvida, mas esper que ajude. Se editar com mais informações, pode ajudar.

Comment: Esse código pelo que entendi detecta se o vídeo está reproduzindo, correto? Eu preciso de um código que detecte quando um vídeo parar para carregar mais conteúdo

Answer (score 0):

Até o momento após alguns testes, este foi o melhor resultado que consegui para determinar se um vídeo parou ou não para carregar conteúdo.

```
setInterval(
    function(){
            if ($(video)[0].paused != true && 
                !$("#video")[0].seeking && 
                 $("#video")[0].readyState >= $("#video")[0].HAVE_FUTURE_DATA) {
                    $(".player-container .player-loading").hide();
            }else{
                $(".player-container .player-loading").show();  
            }
        }, 
 300);
```

Não sei informar se este é um bom método para verificar ou não se o vídeo parou para carregar, mas tem atendido bem a necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés do uso do `setInteval` poderia aproveitar que esta realmente usando jQuery e ajustar usando `onplay`, `onpause`, `onsuspend` e `onwaiting` para algo como:

```
function updateVideo(video) {
    var container = $(video).parents(".player-container");

    if (!video.seeking && video.readyState >= video.HAVE_FUTURE_DATA) {
        $(".player-loading", container).hide();
    } else {
        $(".player-loading", container).show();
    }
}

$(function () {
    $("#video").on("play pause suspend waiting", function(){
        if (this.timeoutCheck) {
             clearTimeout(this.timeoutCheck);
        }

        this.timeoutCheck = setTimeout(updateVideo, 1, this);
    });
});
```

No exemplo eu troque o seletor `$(".player-container .player-loading")` por `.parents()` acaso exista mais de um player na página. o `setTimeout`+`clearTimeout` é para evitar os eventos se conflitarem. Também removi o `video.paused` para evitar com que mostre o "loading" quando pausado pelo usuário

Comment: Mas o problema é que tais eventos de vídeo não funcionam como esperado, com jQuery principalmente levantei até uma outra questão a respeito disso

Comment: @LeoLetto não funcionam? Vou testar em uma internet lenta, mas creio que o pause funcione bem, ou você esta falando da outra resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202269/3635 ?

Comment: Estou optando por usar o método com JS Puro para tais eventos, já que os mesmos não funcionam bem com Ajax / jQuery, só uma dúvida, por que chamar o evento ao usar o play / pause?

Comment: @LeoLetto não tem nada a ver com Ajax, o play e pause sendo no jQuery ou JavaScript será a mesma coisa, o legal do pause é que ele é disparado sendo com suspend ou waiting. Vou ajustar um exemplo sem jQuery (é um pouco complicado)