# Eventos não funcionam com vídeo dinâmico?

Tags: jquery, vídeo, eventos

Estou usando uma página onde o conteúdo é carregado dinamicamente com ajax, o problema é que alguns eventos principalmente os de vídeo não estão funcionando como deveriam, por exemplo:

Meu `functions.js` carregado ao entrar no site:

```
$(document).on("timeupdate", "#video", function(){
    console.log('video playing');
});
```

E então quando o usuário clica para assistir um vídeo eu adiciono o HTML dele numa div e mostro a mesma:

```
$(div).html(player_html);
```

O vídeo reproduz, mas eventos como o citado acima não está sendo disparados, estou evitando ter que carregar o script com os eventos no momento em que eu adicionar o vídeo, como posso resolver esse problema?

O exemplo abaixo parece funcionar bem, mas não me parece uma solução "elegante" para ser usada:

```
document.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e){
    if(e.target.id == "video"){
        console.log('video playing');
    }
}, true);
```

Mas ai surge outra dúvida, se o exemplo acima funcionou, por que o mesmo não funciona com jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que o evento `timeupdate` não é um [*bubble event*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200402/javascript-eventos-bubbles). Isso significa que você não pode tratá-lo através do elemento pai, tal como feito em:

```
$(document).on("timeupdate", "#video", function(){
    console.log('video playing');
});
```

Isso acontece porque o evento fica, no caso, associado ao `document` e não ao elemento `#video`¹. Fazer a delegação do evento direto, com JavaScript puro, é possível da forma que você fez:

```
document.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e){
    if(e.target.id == "video"){
        console.log('video playing');
    }
}, true);
```

As duas formas <strike>não</strike> (possivelmente nem sempre) são análogas².

Ou seja, a única forma (exceto a supracitada) é associar o evento diretamente ao elemento `#video`. Você pode fazer isso no mesmo momento que você o insere no DOM, como explicado pelo Caio, em sua [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/202280/5878), no exemplo 2.

> O exemplo 3 do Caio funcionou da forma apresentada porque o evento `click` é um *bubble event*.

```js
$(() => {

  const player = '<video id="video" width="400" controls><source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"></video>';

  $("button").on("click", event => {
    $("#container").html(player);

    $("#video").on("timeupdate", event => {
      console.log("Video playing...");
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<button>Adicionar</button>
```

**Referências**

[JavaScript | Eventos bubbles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200402/javascript-eventos-bubbles)

[Javascript - Event order](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

[Why don't audio and video events bubble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291651/why-dont-audio-and-video-events-bubble)

[Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

---

**Notas**

**(1)**: De acordo com a página [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) presente no site oficial do jQuery, quando feito algo como:

```
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

O evento `click` é delegado ao elemento `#list` e, quando tratado, é verificado se o alvo do evento combina com o seletor passado no segundo parâmetro. A ler:

> *This second, selector parameter tells the handler to listen for the specified event, and when it hears it, check to see if the triggering element for that event matches the second parameter.*

Conforme o resumo presente na página:

> *Event delegation refers to the process of using event propagation (bubbling) to handle events at a higher level in the DOM than the element on which the event originated. It allows us to attach a single event listener for elements that exist now or in the future.*

A função `on` realmente faz uso do efeito *bubbling*, ou propagação do evento, para esses casos, portanto, para um evento que não se propaga, não funcionará.

**(2)**: Aparentemente as duas formas são análogas quando o evento em questão se propaga pelo DOM, pois o evento disparado no elemento alvo também será disparado em seus elementos antecessores, sendo disparado, portanto, também no elemento `document`. Utilizar o terceiro parâmetro em `addEventListener`, `capture`, como verdadeiro faz com que o evento em questão seja sempre disparado também no elemento em questão, por isso a forma de delegação de evento com JavaScript puro funciona como esperado. Neste caso, fazer algo como o exemplo abaixo também é válido:

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");

container.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
    if(e.target.id == "video"){
        console.log('video playing');
    }
}, true);
```

Ainda não achei nenhuma documentação que fale se a função `on` trate todos os eventos como `bubble` ou se existe um comportamento diferenciado para os eventos que não o são. Em nota 1, diz-se que o evento `on` utiliza, de fato, o efeito *bubbling* do evento para funcionar, mas não é conclusivo se faz isso independente do evento.

Comment: Então eu estava enganado, o .on não funciona como MutationObserver, o evento é adicionado ao pai e não ao novo elemento :/

Comment: Quando o elemento for removido, os eventos vão continuar ativos?

Comment: @LeoLetto se o evento está associado ao elemento, se o mesmo for removido, o evento também será. Não sei se entendi bem a sua pergunta.

Comment: Depois verificarei isso para que eu possa formular uma pergunta melhor se for o caso, acho que terei que optar pelo javascript puro mesmo, é a solução mais rápida e viável pra mim no momento

Comment: Melhor que atribuir o evento quando o vídeo é inserido no DOM? Tem certeza?

Comment: Até onde eu sei, aquelas duas formas são sim análogas. Estranho a versão em js puro ter funcionado, já que esse evento não borbulha...

Comment: @bfavaretto Funcionou por causa do último parâmetro `useCapture` pelo visto. Nesse caso o evento é disparado primeiro para `document` antes de ser disparado no elemento em si, não? Quanto se os códigos são análogos, acredito que não são para todos os eventos. Na função `jQuery.event.add` utilizada por `jQuery.on` tem um comentário assim: "*Only use addEventListener if the special events handler returns false*" (aprox. linha 4600, jQuery 2.2.4, uncompress). Ainda não entendi exatamente o que acontece, mas imagino que o comportamento muda de acordo com o evento tratado.

Comment: Ah, não tinha reparado que aquele código usava capture. Faz sentido que funcione nesse caso. E vou olhar o código do jQuery para tentar entender quando ele usa addEventListener e qua do não usa.

Comment: Excelente. Eu já havia visto alguma coisa sobre o fato do bubbling não ocorrer, mas confesso que não fui tão a fundo quanto queria. Boa resposta

Comment: De acordo com [esse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12630384/4682161) cara, os eventos de áudio e video não borbulham pq não faz sentido para eles. Ele mostra uma maneira de se fazer um wrapper para usar a delegação via jquery. Não testei, mas parece promissor

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira eu havia visto esta resposta quando estava pesquisando, mas achei a solução que ele apresentou inviável e nem citei.  Me pareceu muito código para pouca coisa. Ao meu ver, atribuir o evento ao elemento quando ele é adicionado ao DOM é muito mais prático e simples.

Comment: Como estou fazendo apenas um "upgrade" no código, usar js puro no caso seria a opção mais fácil, pois o mesmo para ser atribuído ao adicionar os elementos exigiria uma certa mudança no meu código atual, já neste caso eu preferiria começar um novo código do 0, prevendo tais acontecimentos no futuro.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, como eu disse, não testei, hahaha. Mas assim, curioso que isso nunca tenha sido tratado no core do jquery

Comment: Acho que porque, de fato, não faz muito sentido fazê-lo. São eventos particulares ao elemento áudio/vídeo, não teria porquê você os tratá-los em uma `div`. No `document`, talvez, mas ainda acho desnecessário.

Answer (score 3):

O seu problema é conhecido, e chama-se [delegação de eventos](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Veja, você mesmo disse que cria os elementos dinamicamente. Isto significa que, no momento em que você declara a rotina do evento, alguns elementos podem ainda não existir. Veja este exemplo:

#### Exemplo 1

```js
//evento para adicionar boxes "dinamicamente"
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var _el = $('<div class="box"></div>');

  $('.container').append(_el);
});

//evento do box, equivalente ao seu evento do video
$('.box').on('click', function(){
  alert('box clicked');
});
```

```css
.box{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container{
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Adicionar box</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Perceba que, se você clicar na primeira *box*, que já existe no momento em que o método é atrelado (*bound*) ao *click*, você recebe um alerta. Caso você crie mais *boxes* e clique nelas, o alerta não ocorre: Por que? De uma maneira simplificada, justamente por conta do fato de que, no momento da declaração, esses elementos novos não existiam.

Você *poderia* corrigir isto declarando o evento junto com a criação do elemento. Veja o próximo exemplo:

#### Exemplo 2

```js
//evento para adicionar boxes "dinamicamente"
$('button').on('click', function(){
  
  //criação do evento junto com o elemento
  var _el = $( "<div/>", {
    "class": "box",
    click: function() {
      alert('box clicked');
    }
  });
  
  $('.container').append(_el);
});

//evento do box, equivalente ao seu evento do video
$('.box').on('click', function(){
  alert('box clicked');
});
```

```css
.box{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container{
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Adicionar box</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Veja que agora os novos *boxes* executam o alerta quando clicados. Mas existe um revés: Eu tive que declarar o evento duas vezes - uma para as *boxes* já existentes, e outra para as novas *boxes*, no momento da criação (experimente remover a segunda declaração para ver o que acontece).

Existe uma terceira maneira, a que eu acredito ser a melhor, que é justamente com a delegação dos eventos. Você pode atrelar (*bind*) o evento de um elemento ao *pai* deste elemento, fazendo com que seja obrigatória apenas a existência do pai, e não dos elementos em sí. Veja o terceiro exemplo:

#### Exemplo 3:

```js
//evento para adicionar boxes "dinamicamente"
$('button').on('click', function(){
  
  var _el = $('<div class="box"></div>');
  
  $('.container').append(_el);
  
});

//evento do box, equivalente ao seu evento do video
$('.container').on('click', '.box', function(){
  alert('box clicked');
});
```

```css
.box{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container{
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Adicionar box</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Veja que agora eu atribui o evento ao *container* (ou seja, o pai, que eu tenho certeza que existe) e, como parâmetro adicional, informei o filho `.box`, que é aonde eu quero efetivamente atrelar o meu evento. Perceba que desta maneira, a ação ocorre tanto pra elementos que existiam previamente quanto para novos, contanto que eles sejam do tipo `.box` (no seu caso, algo como `.video`). A única obrigatoriedade é que você utilize um elemento pai (`.container`) que *com certeza* vai existir no momento da execução do código. Se não, você recorre no problema.

#### Pontos de atenção:

1. [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) está deprecado. É recomendado o uso de [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (que é o que te permite fazer a delegação).
2. Se você está dinamicamente criando elementos `#video`, utilize uma classe (`.video`), já que IDs devem sempre ser únicos na página.

Comment: Conforme o exemplo 3 se eu declarar `$(document).on("timeupdate", "#video", function(){})` deveria funcionar, mas aqui não funcionou, ou eu devo substituir o `document` por um elemento da página?

Comment: Estou ciente do uso de ID para o vídeo, este é meu único elemento com tal ID

Comment: como você está fazendo a injeção do conteúdo?

Comment: Tenho todo o HTML para o player de vídeo salvo em uma variável do JS, e então quando o usuário clica para assistir algo, eu adiciono essa variável a `div` responsável por exibir o conteúdo dinâmico com `$(".minha-div").html(player);`

Comment: Tudo depende de como está o seu HTML dentro dessa variável.  `timeupdate`também é um evento só para as tags multimedia, então veja se está atribuindo no lugar certo

Comment: Não entendi, o HTML dentro da div está normal, basicamente `player = "<video id='#video' poster='' src=''></video>` tem mais HTML  ser carregado junto, mas não creio que seja relevante aqui

Comment: O mais estranho é que no console do navegador o evento está listado no meu elemento, ou estou errado? http://imgur.com/a/C7VLn

Comment: Não.. parece estar tudo correto. vou dar uma pesquisada aqui

Comment: Caio, adicionei na pergunta um exemplo que funcionou e talvez ajude você a entender a causa do problema para me ajudar.

Comment: Eu já vi alguma coisa parecida. Deixa eu ver se acho

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira, eu [respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/202990/5878) a pergunta também. Veja se concorda, caso ainda não tenha visto. Talvez seja do seu interesse também.