# Como o "on" do jQuery funciona?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo alguns testes, e, tenho uns eventos personalizados na plataforma que utilizo, porém, o window.addEventListener não funciona conforme o on() do jQuery.

o evento que utilizo, vamos supor que o nome seja shoppingCartUpdated, ele é acionado através do window.

Conforme eu faço isso no jQuery, funciona normalmente

```
$(window).on('shoppingCartUpdated', function(e){
    console.log(e);
})
```

Porém, com o addEventListener, não.

```
window.addEventListener('shoppingCartUpdated', function(e){
   console.log(e);
});
```

Sei que funcionam de forma diferentes, pois se não o pessoal do jQuery não criaria o on. Mas, ja tentei de algumas formas olhar o codigo fonte do jQuery e não entendi muito bem como ele funcion. É possível reproduzir o mesmo efeito?

Quando digo "funcionar", quero dizer que com o jQuery ele imprimi o console.log, com o addEventListner não.

Comment: O que é o `evt` que você passou para o `addEventListener`?

Comment: @Woss desculpa, eu editei. Agora está certo.

Comment: Outra pergunta: esse seu evento personalizado, `shoppingCartUpdated`, é um *bubble event*? Isto é, ele se propaga pelos elementos pais do alvo original do evento? Seria interessante você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar informações de como criou e disparou o evento.

Comment: @Woss como é a plataforma "SaaS" que fez esse evento, e não eu, eu não posso te afirmar isso. Eu consigo saber dessa informação por alguma saída no console do jQuery? Posso colar o que o jQuery me retorna aqui...

Comment: Qualquer informação extra pode ser útil... coloque o que conseguir de informações do evento na pergunta

Comment: Como está executando o trigger do `shoppingCartUpdated` com JavaScript puro?

Comment: Se for de interesse, eu comentei sobre o funcionamento do `jQuery.on` em [Eventos não funcionam com vídeo dinâmico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202269/5878)